# Parameter expansion default value to empty array

Tags: bash, shell

```
: ${my_parameter:=()}
```

sets `my_parameter` to the `()` string instead of an empty array but I want an empty array.

Comment: try this: var_name=()
for i in {1..10}; do
    var_name[$i]="Field $i of the list"
done

Comment: There's no such thing as an empty array value. An unset parameter with its array attribute set *is* an empty array.

Comment: `my_parameter=()` actually *unsets* the variable (try `[[ -v my_parameter ]] || echo unset`), while setting the array attribute on the name.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the following:

```
declare -a my_parameter
```

If `my_parameter` is an existing array, it is left untouched.  Otherwise a new and empty array named `my_parameter` is created.